# Why is viewDidUnload called less often than viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I put `NSLog(@"%@::%@", [[self class] description], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));` in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` of a view controller.

In the log, I found `viewDidLoad` is called a lot more than `viewDidUnload` when the app moves to and from different .nibs.

Why?

Comment: I just wonder that if my answer is accepted, I will have +50 repu, right? Why didn't I receive that?

Comment: @vodkhang, my fault. I didn't realize I have to click Accept and the `+50` icon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload is not corresponding to each other.

The viewDidUnload will only be called when you receive a memory warning. The system then will automatically call your viewDidUnload.

In the normal case, when you push a MyViewController and pop it out. The life cycle will happens like this:

```
init

viewDidLoad

release
```

That means, whenever you init and push/present a view, a viewDidLoad will be called. But when you pop the view, the release will be called in normal case and viewDidUnload will be called in memory warning case.

This is quite implicit and Apple doesn't state it clearly on the Guide. Here is some reference: [Load and Unload cycle](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW19)

Comment: Then what's the difference between viewDidUnload and didRecieveMemoryWarning?

Comment: First, The application receives a low-memory warning from the system. Then each view controller calls its didReceiveMemoryWarning method. Then, If the view controller releases its view, it calls its viewDidUnload method. You can override this method to perform any additional cleanup required for your views and view hierarchy.

Comment: Look at the link of Load and Unload cycle again

Comment: The problem I'm finding is that init is also called every time the view controller is added to the nav stack... So where should I put my one-time initialize code?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that in the cases where `-viewDidUnload` wasn't called, the view controller was released.

1. viewDidLoad: controller loads view
2. viewDidUnload: memory warning, controller unloads view
3. viewDidLoad: controller loads view again
4. -: controller gets released, doesn't explicitly unload the view

You and up with 2 `-viewDidLoad` calls and 1 `-viewDidUnload' call.

Maybe also put a `NSLog` into the `-dealloc` method and see if the number of `-dealloc` and `-viewDidUnload` calls combined matches the number of `-viewDidLoad` calls.

Answer (score 0):

when a new view loads, the old view can still be loaded in the background.
you are searching for viewWillAppear as conterpart i think.

views only unload in case of a memorywarning.