# Releasing/accessing different objects of the same name in different classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm a newbie to objective-c (and all things Apple, for that matter).

I'm designing an iOS app and ran into a bug that seemed pretty interesting to me. Basically, I started out in a VC (LoginViewController), and somewhere along the the way I would push another VC onto my navigation controller (MyProfileViewController).

But when I backed my way through the stack back to LoginViewController, touching any object on the screen would cause an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error. After some head scratching, I decided to change the table names in the views (both of my ViewControllers contained a `UITableView`, defined in their respective .m files, and both of which I named 'myTable').

It turned out that for my app, aside from contributing to poor readability (you don't have to berate me on this point), naming both of the tables the same was what was causing the crash. So I guess that when MyProfileViewController was being deallocated, it released 'myTable' from LoginViewController as well???

With normal bugs, I realize my error, try to learn from it, and move on. But this just doesn't make sense to me as to why it's creating a crash in the first place. Any insights? For reference, here's how I was defining and releasing the UITableView in both of the ViewControllers.

```
@implementation MyProfileViewController//same format as LoginViewController

UITableView* myTable;//It's since been renamed to something more descriptive

//code...

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [myUpdateTable setDataSource:self];
    [myTable setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:myTable];
}

//code...

-(void)dealloc{
    [myTable release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: ideally this should not happen. you can try one thing. choose the same name and in the dealloc before releasing table, first write these two line of code - tableView.delegate = nil; tableView.datasource = nil;

Comment: There must be something else going on here.  The names are only valid within their scope, which is only the owning object in this case.  Anything interesting going on in `LoginViewController`'s `viewDidUnload`?

Comment: Hmm. @rishi I tried setting the delegate and datasource to nil in the dealloc but it didn't affect anything. Phillip Mills I thought that might be a good location to check, so I commented everything out but [super viewDidUnload] and it's still happening. This is quite odd.

Comment: @user1080952 - have you enabled NSZombie in your project, i doubt something else is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do I read your code correctly, that your `UITableView` is not defined in the `@interface`? If that's so, you've defined `myTable` to be a global variable. That's not a good idea, though I'm surprised the linker didn't complain if you used the same global variable in two .m files (but it would certainly explain why using the same name caused problems). You really want your `UITableView` to be an instance variable. You could define the private instance variable at the top of your .m file as follows (put this before the `@implementation`):

```
@interface MyProfileViewController ()
{
    UITableView* _myTable;
}
@end
```

If you do this, then it doesn't matter whether the name of your instance variable in one class happens to be the same as one in another class. The scope of an class instance variable is limited to that class. (By the way, as a matter of style, many people preface their class instance variables with underscores, generally to differentiate them from class properties and local variables.)

Second (and unrelated to your original question), I'd suggest releasing in `viewDidLoad`, thus:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [_myTable setDataSource:self];
    [_myTable setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:_myTable];
    [_myTable release];
}
```

(And, obviously, remove the `release` statement from your `dealloc`.)

There's no reason to defer the `release`: When you alloc/init, it has a retain count of +1, when you `addSubview` it gets a retain count of +2, and when you release, you simply return the release count back to +1 (meaning that it won't be dealloced because `self.view` is retaining it but when the view eventually releases it, your tableview will be dealloced automatically for you). There are, though, good reasons to *not* defer it (your original code will leak if you got a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` after pushing to a new view controller).

If you use ARC, this sort of silly memory management issue is generally cleaned up for you, but given you're not using ARC, you might want to adjust where you release.

Comment: Creating it as an instance variable did the trick and now I can have them be the same name (the tables are renamed now for readability anyways). I am planning on using ARC for my next project, but as a beginner, I'd like to get as much understanding about memory management in objective-c as possible before using its' nice new features.

Comment: Nicely done.  I'm so brainwashed into seeing variables only in interfaces that I read it that way even when it's not there.  :)