# How can I compare viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

How can I compare `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: what you want to compare? viewDidLoad runs one time when view is loaded and viewDidAppear runs everytime when view is appearing on the screen

Comment: put NSLog on both functions to understand which is called when..

Comment: Refer more on this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254697/difference-between-viewdidload-and-viewdidappear

Answer (score 7):

The best thing to do is to implement both methods in a view controller that loads a view with subviews (easiest is from a NIB) and put a breakpoint into each method. When the app stops on each breakpoint, look at the Variables view in the debugger and see what objects have been instantiated.

To eliminate confusion about the `UIViewController` lifecycle, here's a diagram taken from Big Nerd Ranch iOS Programming:

[image]

Comment: is this answer to question or comment to question?

Comment: @P.J This is an answer.

Comment: if you by the question title, this is an answer :D

Comment: You should put more description, elaborate like put NSLog, debugging is dam difficult.. Also, you can put code when is viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear Called..

Comment: +1, now its look as perfect answer.. :)