# How can I know when a `UIViewController` has been just pushed from a `UINavigationViewController`?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I know when a `UIViewController` has been just pushed from a `UINavigationViewController` ?

I obviously don't want to use `viewDidAppear` because that's method is called everytime that view appears, not just when it's pushed.

`viewDidLoad` is called *before* the view controller is pushed and I don't have the reference to the navigationController available

Comment: from [this diagram](https://rdkw.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/) I don't see other events sent besides the ones you mentioned. You could use `viewDidAppear` with a boolean value like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207063/how-to-do-some-stuff-in-viewdidappear-only-once)

Comment: Have a look at [UIViewController:willMoveToParentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willMoveToParentViewController:) or the alikes

Comment: Unfortunately willMoveToParentViewController is called also when the controller is popped.

Comment: @Patrick But when popped, the parent parameter will be `nil`.

Comment: @maddy Yes, indeed. It has been discussed in Sulthan answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. The simplest way. When pushing the controller, set a flag on it. You know when you are pushing, you can run custom code at that moment.
2. `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and its `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:`. Again, you can make the controller the delegate or just call a method on it externally.
3. Logic inside the controller - You can probably use a combination of `viewDidAppear` and `willMoveToParentViewController:`. Initially, when the controller appears, it has been pushed. After that, you can reset the "pushed" state when the controller is removed from the navigation controller when listening to changes of parent controller. Your use case is not very clear but in some cases you could just handle the first `viewDidAppear` call and it would work.

However, note the first two options are far easier to implement. That's because you are trying to listen to an event from a class that shouldn't know about that event.
The most sensible solution in that case is listen to that event somewhere else and setup the controller *externally* to handle that event.

Comment: 1. Why shouldn't the pushed view controller know when it's pushed?

Comment: 2. Why do you say "a combination of viewDidAppear and willMoveToParentViewController"? As @TomKnapen commented willMoveToParentViewController is called when the view controller is pushed, therefore solution 3 seems the simplest and most correct to me.

Comment: @Patrick Because it's not the responsibility of the controller to know how it has been shown. That's the responsibility of the navigation controller or any other container class.

Comment: If it is not its responsibility, what about didAppear and willMoveToParentViewController then? The responsibility should be of the parent controllers in this case too, but still the view controller has these methods.

Comment: @Patrick `willMoveToParentViewController` will be called also in other situations, e.g. when the controller is `popped`. From your question I wasn't very sure whether you are showing the controller in multiple ways (e.g. pushing at one place, presenting at another place). In that case using `willMoveToParentViewController` would not work because it is not detecting pushing, it is detecting moving to a parent controller.

Comment: Ah I see. willMoveToParentViewController is called also when it's popped indeed. That's not what I want.

Comment: @Patrick You might notice that `willMoveToParentViewController` will have a different (`nil`) parameter when the controller is popped so it could actually work in your case.

Comment: I see, indeed. I could use that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> You can check this from of navigation viewcontrollers array

```
//Eg:
//Maintain your navigation object:
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;

//use:
   if([[self.navController.viewControllers lastObject] class] == [your view controoler class]) {
  // your view controller is present in navigation stack
}
```

Comment: this is just demonstration, you can use this along as per your requirements.

Comment: First of all, that navigation controller would have to be `weak`. Second, why would you check class equality? Just compare `lastObject` to that controller directly

Comment: But I meant, inside the class of the view controller that has just been added. (That's why I mentioned viewDidAppear, or viewDIdLoad: I'm clearly inside the pushed view controller class).

Comment: you can give try to methods: viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews these methods called after view is loaded

Comment: "These methods called after view is loaded": which is not what I've asked.

Comment: ok. so you want know that in that controller itself which is pushed?

Comment: Check the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from `viewDidAppear`.  set a flag or `bool` status to `true` or `YES` when pushed from previous VC. and then put condition in `viewDidAppear` that if status or flag is true then only do some stuff that you want to do on push. when you pop from another view to current view set this flag or status to `NO` so, your condition from `viewDidAppear` will not execute.