# how to check viewController is viewed for the first time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I am running [instruction framework at this link](https://github.com/ephread/Instructions).

1. I am checking the application launched for the first time by this code:

   ```swift
   func isFirstTimeOpening() -> Bool {
       let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

       if(defaults.integer(forKey: "hasRun") == 0) {
           defaults.set(1, forKey: "hasRun")
           return true
       }
       return false

   }
   ```

   I am calling it in `viewWillAppear`

   ```swift
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       if isFirstTimeOpening(){
           self.startInstructions()   //1
           self.coachMarksController.dataSource = self   //2
       }

   }
   ```

Here is my `viewDidAppear` function

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        //if isFirstTimeOpening()  {
        self.coachMarksController.start(in: .window(over: self))
        coachMarksController.delegate = self
       // }
    }
```

2. Second thing that i want to check for commented 1 & 2  is First viewController is Loading collectionView is **viewed for the first time**. This is because function `func isFirstTimeOpening() -> Bool` checks only **application launched for the first time** not viewController is visited multiple time during the first launch. I want to restrict these commands `self.startInstructions()` `self.coachMarksController.dataSource = self` to execute for first time viewed only(viewController having collectionView) ? How can do that?

Comment: Setting a bool in user defaults is a good idea. Why don't you just do it in the hooks that match your conditions?  So, did user launch the app?  Do that in the app delegate on applicationDidFinishLaunching.  Did user see VC_X?  Do that in VC_X's viewDidAppear hook, and so on for embedded vcs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do some stuff in viewDidAppear only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207063/how-to-do-some-stuff-in-viewdidappear-only-once)

Comment: I'm unclear what the question is. The code in point 1 will correctly determine whether it has every been called before (whether during this launch of the app or previous launches of the app), though as danh pointed out, we would generally use a boolean rather than an integer for this. Are you saying that this view controller might be presented multiple times during the first launch and that you don't want to `hasRun` to be set yet?

Comment: Explanation: After the first launch if i move from viewControllerA to viewControllerB. After that i return back to viewControllerA.It is still going to `if isFirstTimeOpening(){` as true statement and executing it as first time launch.Because the first time launch has not been broken and replaced by second launch