# Hiding tableHeaderView behind of the Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, navigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have used following line of code for adding a search bar as a `tableHeaderView`:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
```

But my problem is hiding it like the iOS apps. On the iBooks app's search bar always behind of the Navigation Bar. I don't found any related documentations from the Apple's Documentations.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide this bar from the start, you can use `setContentOffset`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632860/1822214):

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 44), animated: false)
```

This should hide the search bar from the start.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have called your suggestion inside of the viewDidLoad method

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 44), animated: false)
        }
    }
` This is works well. Thanks for your help

Comment: That's odd. I wonder why it works with a delay. Have you tried it without the delay an `animated: true`?

Comment: Try putting it in `viewDidAppear` instead. [It occurs later in the lifecycle of the UIViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22215127/1822214)

Comment: Thanks very much!