# Is viewDidLoad called when popping back in the view controller hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm wondering if, once a view controller somewhere in a navigation controller hierarchy is created, is it reloaded when you pop back to it after it has already previously been loaded?

Comment: No. Only viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are called. You should try it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're popping/dismissing back to it, `viewDidLoad` is not generally called, but `viewDidAppear` will.

The exception to this is in iOS versions prior to 6.0, if you received a memory warning, your view could be unloaded, and it will be reloaded when you pop back.

Comment: you mean if I have a navigation stack of 1(rootViewController),2 and am currently at 1 ie 1 is my *topviewController*. and I go from 1 to 2 and then go back to 1. Isn't 2 kicked out of memory? and if I go back from 1 to 2 again isn't viewDidLoad loaded from **scratch**?

Comment: You're correct, but that's not what the OP asked. He asked whether, when you pop back from 2 to 1, whether `viewDidLoad` is called again on 1. But of course, 2 is typically released when you pop from it and it will be recreated from scratch if you push to a new instance of 2.

Comment: I never thought of it that way, but I'm not 100% if that is what he was asking. But I guess with the comments now it leaves no doubt. I'd suggest you include this in the answer or differentiate. I was lost for a few minutes...

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm pretty sure about the OP's intent here. It was a completely logical question back in 2013, because in olden days (pre iOS 6), in low memory situations it actually _could_ unload 1 when you pushed from 1 to 2 and when you popped back, it actually might need to reload 1 again. There was much confusion over this topic back then. (This is part of the reason why Apple simplified it, as it created tremendous confusion for negligible gain.)

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this one

[Difference between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254697/difference-between-viewdidload-and-viewdidappear)

> viewDidLoad is called exactly once, when the view controller is first
>   loaded into memory. This is where you want to instantiate any instance
>   variables and build any views that live for the entire lifecycle of
>   this view controller. However, the view is usually not yet visible at
>   this point.