# In Swift How to change the selected tab bar

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift programming and I have a Tabbed application with 2 UITabBar items , I want that when user taping the second tab, application set the selected tab index to 0 and move user to the first tab. I tried this code in my `SecondViewController.swift's viewDidLoad` :

```js
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work?  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254697/difference-between-viewdidload-and-viewdidappear) for a good explanation of viewDidLoad() vs. viewDidAppear.

Relevant excerpt:

> This is where you want to perform any layout actions or do any drawing in the UI - for example, presenting a modal view controller