# How to create a pop-up alert once the view loads in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, popup, alert

I need a simple alert that pops up when the view loads on the screen. I've found a couple of tutorials on how to create a pop-up alert but they all require that a UIbutton is pressed. I need it to just automatically pop up when the view loads.

This is a start to my code, however I can't figure out how to call upon the code without having to use a UIbutton action:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Disclaimer", message:
        "Hello, world!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> alert that pops up when the view loads on the screen

The problem is that "load" does not *mean* "on the screen". You are conflating two different things. `viewDidLoad` merely means that the view controller *has* a view. The view does not appear *on the screen* until `viewDidAppear:`. So that's the place to put this code.

Comment: Awesome! That makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: @Benpeterswake http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254697/difference-between-viewdidload-and-viewdidappear good information on what matt is talking about. You definitely want to understand the view lifecycle fully.