# Why my alert is not in the view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, hierarchy, uialertcontroller

I found that my controller is out of the view hierarchy in this code andI call this in viewDidLoad:

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    // code
} else {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(...)
    //
    present(alertController)
}
```

If I wrap else clause in .async or .asyncAfter in the main queue I have my  issue go away.
Why do this happen here?

Thank you!

Comment: i think you called UIAlertController in viewdidload , try in viewdidappear

Comment: This method called in viewDidLoad! Here is the issue I suppose?

Comment: yes ,see the difference between viewdidload or viewdidappear : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254697/difference-between-viewdidload-and-viewdidappear

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I got it. View is not in the hierarchy when alert appeared. My bad!

Comment: welcome .......

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik posts your answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your question you are tried  to load UIAlertController before load the UIviewcontroller hierarchy, in here you can do it two ways,

- you can forcefully load the UIAlertController in the main thread, so in here you need to use .async or .asyncAfter, but **it's not suggested**.
- alternate suggestion but it will works fine,  you need to wait for your initial UI view hierarchy, I mean you need to convert your code from viewDidLoad to  viewDidAppear. for ref : [Difference between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254697/difference-between-viewdidload-and-viewdidappear)

Comment: "load the UIAlertController in the main thread". What does that even mean? You cannot use `viewWillAppear. You have to use `viewDidAppear` because otherwise `self` is not in the view hierarchy yet and there is no way to present a controller outside the view hierarchy.